# GWT and tomcat development

Tags: mysql, gwt, tomcat

I been playing around a bit with GWT using the built in jetty server, purely in development mode, and I am now wondering if the framework will be fit for purpose for a project we are starting shortly.

We need to deploy on a tomcat server, and we need to be able to use a mysql connection pool on that tomcat server to populate the domain model of the GWT application. So we wont really be using the Jetty server built into jetty at all. So, here's the questions:

1. Is there any way of running the development mode up against Tomcat rather than the built in server? If no, what is the alternative? Debugging/run on a external server?
2. I've tried configuring the run on external server, but amending the arguments, so it doesnt use the built in jetty instance and it deploys to my tomcat webapps directory. But files from the /war folder seems to be missing. Can anybody explain or point me to a resource documenting this?
3. Have I overlooked something in GWT that will make it pain full to use a JNDI datasource as made available from tomcat?
4. would it actually be possible to use the tomcat JDNI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT places no limitation on what you can do on server, so unless there is a specific bug somewhere you should be able to use Tomcat JNDI.

As for running the GWT development mode against tomcat, yes it is possible. GWT Developer Guide [covers this question](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s). GWT eclipse plugin makes it even easier. You can just right-click on your project, select "Run As", and then select "Web Application (running on external server)".

Comment: thanks for the answer :) i will accept it, but just one thing, as i said in the question i have actually tried it. and it didnt move everything over (i read in the docs that i would need to manually move over certain other files, which would be a bit of a pain since i use spring as well :)) I ended up modifying the run config and basically have tomcat serving the war directory directly

Comment: @Just: The Google (GWT) Plugin doesn't deploy any files to your external server (unless there is a new feature I haven't heard of yet). If you want to push things automatically to your server, you can use Eclipse's JavaEE tools (WTP/WST). They can be used in combination with the Google Plugin, but you may have to play around with it a little bit.